# Pandas calculate percent from two data frames by joining specify index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I generated two Dataframe (df1, df2).
How to calculate the difference between two Dataframe to generate the Final Dataframe?
Calculate the percentage difference by Date : (df1-df2)/df2.

df1:

|  |  | Score1 | Score2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date | Student |  |  |
| 2005-01-01 | Peter | 15 | 18 |
| 2005-03-01 | Peter | 110 | 330 |
|  | John | 120 | 360 |
|  | Mary | 90 | 210 |
|  | Alan | 115 | 270 |

df2:

|  |  | Score1 | Score2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date | Student |  |  |
| 2005-01-01 | Standard | 10 | 20 |
| 2005-03-01 | Standard | 100 | 300 |

final Dataframe:

|  |  | Score1 | Score2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date | Student |  |  |
| 2005-01-01 | Peter | 0.5 | -0.1 |
| 2005-03-01 | Peter | 0.1 | 0.1 |
|  | John | 0.2 | 0.2 |
|  | Mary | -0.1 | -0.3 |
|  | Alan | 0.15 | -0.1 |

Answer (score 0):

You can remove second level of `df2` by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) or [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df22 = df2.droplevel(1)
#alternative
#df22 = df2.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

df = df1.sub(df22).div(df22)
print (df)
                    Score1  Score2
Date       Student                
2005-01-01 Peter      0.50    -0.1
2005-03-01 Peter      0.10     0.1
           John       0.20     0.2
           Mary      -0.10    -0.3
           Alan       0.15    -0.1
```

Or if need select level `Standard`:

```
df22 = df2.xs('Standard', level=1)     
df = df1.sub(df22).div(df22)
```

Comment: Get my expected result. Thanks a lot!